# Adding struct fields

Tags: struct, scheme, racket

So, I have a Racket `struct`, stats :

```
(struct stats (str con dex int wis cha))
```

And I have a function `add-stats`:

```
(define (modify-stats mods base)
   (stats (+ (stats-str mods)
             (stats-str base))
          (+ (stats-con mods)
             (stats-con base))
          (+ (stats-dex mods)
             (stats-dex base))
          (+ (stats-int mods)
             (stats-int base))
          (+ (stats-wis mods)
             (stats-wis base))
          (+ (stats-cha mods)
             (stats-cha base))))
```

Obviously this is real messy and there's a lot of unwanted repetition involved. I managed to cut it down some to a more-readable version:

```
(define (modify-stats mods base)
    (define (add-stat statid)
        (+ (statid mods)
           (statid base)))

    (stats (add-stat stats-str)
           (add-stat stats-con)
           (add-stat stats-dex)
           (add-stat stats-int)
           (add-stat stats-wis)
           (add-stat stats-cha)))
```

But there's still a lot of repetition of "stat(s)" in there. Is there a cleaner way I can preform operations on the fields of two structs of the same type?

---

UPDATE:
I've managed to make it a little better like so:

```
(define (stat a-stat stats)
  (match a-stat
    ["str" (stats-str stats)]
    ["con" (stats-con stats)]
    ["dex" (stats-dex stats)]
    ["int" (stats-int stats)]
    ["wis" (stats-wis stats)]
    ["cha" (stats-cha stats)]
    [_ (error "Not a stat!")]))

(define (modify-stats mods base)
  (define (add-stat string)
    (+ (stat string mods)
       (stat string base)))
  (stats (add-stat "str")
         (add-stat "con")
         (add-stat "dex")
         (add-stat "int")
         (add-stat "wis")
         (add-stat "cha")))
```

Comment: Perhaps it's because I'm just not that bright, but the second way of performing the operation reads about as clearly as I can imagine the code reading. Unless there was a compelling reason, such as many different structures with similar operations, that looks like what I would want to have to maintain. If a generic approach was appropriate, then I'd want to pass in the operations like `add-stat` rather than hard wiring it. `This question seems more appropriate for StackExchange Code Review since the code is working.`

Answer (score 4):

Without resorting to reflection, here's one way to do it:

```
(define (modify-stats mods base)
  (define (get-fields obj)
    (map (lambda (getter) (getter obj))
         (list stats-str stats-con stats-dex stats-int stats-wis stats-cha)))
  (apply stats (map + (get-fields mods) (get-fields base))))
```

---

Loath as I am to suggest using macros to improve performance, this macro generates exactly the same code as the OP's first version:

```
(require (for-syntax racket/syntax))
(define modify-stats
  (let-syntax
      ((bump (lambda (stx)
               (define (bump-attr attr)
                 (with-syntax ((getter (format-id attr "stats-~a" attr #:source attr)))
                   #'(+ (getter mods) (getter base))))
               (syntax-case stx ()
                 ((_ attr ...)
                  (with-syntax (((bumped ...) (map bump-attr (syntax->list #'(attr ...)))))
                    #'(lambda (mods base)
                        (stats bumped ...))))))))
    (bump str con dex int wis cha)))
```

Comment: This version is around 17x slower than the OP's first version, and 3x slower than the OP's second. So if performance mattered, I'd stick to the initial version.

Comment: Totally understandable. The first version is trivial to inline. The second adds more indirection cost, and mine takes it up another notch. :-)

Comment: Agreed. So the "ideal" solution would be a syntactic extension that generated the first version, using reflection. Do you think that is feasible?

Comment: I am actually writing a proof-of-concept macro for such a thing, but without using reflection (since that has a cost, too).

Comment: Okay, the macro is written now. It's, uh, not the most elegant thing in the world, but hopefully still has less code duplication than the original. ;-)

Comment: +1 for accepting the challenge ;-)